# Getting Make to automatically detect changes in protocol buffers

Tags: makefile

I want Make to automatically compile protos when I update them, here is what I've got so far:

```
TARGET=main

BIN_DIR=bin
SRC_DIR=src
OBJ_DIR=obj

PROTO_DIR=protos/
PROTO_COMPILE_DIR=src/$(PROTO_DIR)

CC       = g++
CFLAGS   = -Wall -std=c++17 -ggdb -pipe -I.
LINKER   = g++
LFLAGS   = $(CFLAGS) -lprotobuf

SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.cc) \
      $(wildcard src/protos/*.cc) \
      $(wildcard src/db_handler/*.cc)

OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cc=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET): proto $(OBJECTS) 
    @mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)/
    $(LINKER) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc
    @mkdir -p obj/ obj/protos obj/db_handler
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: proto
proto:
    @printf "Compiling protos...\n"
    @cd $(PROTO_DIR) && protoc * --grpc_out=../$(PROTO_COMPILE_DIR)\
        --cpp_out=../$(PROTO_COMPILE_DIR)\
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="/usr/local/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin"\
        && cd ../
```

It successfully compiles protos; but, it does so every time, even if there are no changes in files. How can I prevent this and compile protos only if protos change?

Edit: Added project structure

```
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── makefile
    ├── protos
    │   ├── client.proto
    │   └── person.proto
    ├── README.md
    └── src
        ├── db_handler
        │   ├── db_handler.cc
        │   └── db_handler.h
        ├── main.cc
        └── protos
            ├── client.grpc.pb.cc
            ├── client.grpc.pb.h
            ├── client.pb.cc
            ├── client.pb.h
            ├── person.grpc.pb.cc
            ├── person.grpc.pb.h
            ├── person.pb.cc
            └── person.pb.h
```

Comment: Because you mark it `.PHONY`, right?  Doesn't that always make it out of date?

Comment: @FiddlingBits I removed `.PHONY` and it still runs every time

Comment: It actually forces the whole project to rebuild, which is pretty annoying

Comment: Is there actually a file named `proto`?  If it doesn't exist, maybe Make will always run that rule.

Comment: @FiddlingBits yes proto files exist, I will update post with my project structure

Comment: So, you don't have a file specifically named `proto`.  Maybe you need rules named `client.grpc.pb.cc`, for example.

Comment: Oh right, so I should add a rule for every `.cc` file in `src/protos`, correct?

Comment: Possibly.  Make can definitely be tricky.

Comment: Your idea worked! Thank you sir

Comment: You want to add the source files of the protos to the right (the prerequisites) of the rule that cares about them, then make will understand that their time stamps need tracking.

Comment: @unDeadHerbs what do you mean? What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: You'd want the rule to be structured as `$(PROTOS): $(PROTO_SOURCES)`.  Then Make will understand that this is the rule which cares about those source files.  As you currently have it, the rule has no prerequisites and so might never be run once the targets exist, even if they are older than the sources (since it can't tell that without the prerequisite).

Comment: @unDeadHerbs thank you! I get it now. You saved me another make headache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add the source files of the protocol buffers to the right (the prerequisites) of the rule that cares about them. This is how Make understands and tracks their time stamps.

By adding the files to the prerequisites, Make will understand that this is the rule which cares about those source files.

```
PROTO_SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(PROTO_DIR)/*.proto)
PROTOS         := $(patsubst $(PROTO_DIR)/%.proto,$(PROTO_COMPILE_DIR)/%.cc,$(PROTO_SOURCES))

$(PROTOS): $(PROTO_SOURCES)
    @printf "Compiling protos...\n"
    @cd $(PROTO_DIR) && protoc * --grpc_out=../$(PROTO_COMPILE_DIR)\
        --cpp_out=../$(PROTO_COMPILE_DIR)\
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="/usr/local/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin"
```

However, this `$(PROTOS) : $(PROTO_SOURCES)` is not good if you use parallel builds; because, Make will try to run the command once for each output file. So, make will run N instances of the command at the same time, which means they may clobber each other.

In order to know the fully correct solution you need to provide more information (for those not familiar with protoc). Is it a requirement that you invoke protoc once with all inputs? Or is it valid to run protoc individually on each input .proto file to get its output? Then you can write a pattern rule that generates one file at a time.

---

Note 1: As to your other attempt, if you use `.PHONY` to mark the rule then Make will rebuild the rule every time weather it needs to or not.

Note 2: You don't need the `cd ..` at the end of the second instruction, since it is run in a sub shell.

Comment: That's  great but now if I delete `src/protos/*` the rule doesn't run at all, any idea why?

Comment: Because there are no source files that are newer than the targets.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, if i `echo $(PROTOS)` it prints an empty line

Comment: Sorry, I didn't checking the variable definitions before copying them. I've verified them now.

Comment: Thanks! But how should I structure my make now? I clearly want o run `$(PROTOS)` before creating object files.
But if I run 
`$(OBJECTS): $(PROTOS) $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc`
I get multiple targets error

Comment: You want  to describe the rule in terms of a single file pattern and it's prerequisites.  `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc $(PROTOS) ` If you need to track more complex dependencies, you'll either want to describe them to make manually  or look into https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html .

Comment: Thank you, this works, I will look into the link you provided as well

Comment: This `$(PROTOS) : $(PROTO_SOURCES)` is not right.  You virtually never want to have multiple targets in a single explicit rule.  This may work "by accident" if you always run serially (never enable parallel builds with `-j`) but it will fail _hard_ if you run with `-j`.  In order to know the right solution you need to provide more information (for those not familiar with `protoc`).  Is it a requirement that you invoke `protoc` once with all inputs?  Or is it valid to run `protoc` individually on each input `.proto` file to get its output?

Comment: I agree that they should be separate rules for readability and build times. But why would them all being one cause failures if parallel builds is enabled? Won't make just stop being parallel while this rule runs (as it bottle necks the dependency graph)?

Comment: @MadScientist thank you for your input, I figured this much myself when I created better proto files, separating functionalities to different files and packages. Your proposal is indeed better

Comment: Because make will try to run the command once for each output file.  If you are running serially then it will run the command once, then all the subsequent commands will not be run because the first command would make them up to date.  But if you run in parallel make will run N instances of the command at the same time because when make checks, the targets are out of date, which means they may all overwrite each other.

Comment: @MadScientist Thatnks, I've updated the answer to contain that warning.

Comment: If it's correct to run `protoc` on each file, you can use `$(D)/%.grpc.pb.cc $(D)/%.grpc.pb.h $(D)/%.pb.cc $(D)/%.pb.h : protos/%.proto ; cd ... && protoc $< ...` and it will work.  Note you don't need to use `cd ..` because each recipe line runs in its own shell, so any `cd` operation has no effect for make itself.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @FiddlingBits I managed to figure out how to do it correctly

```
TARGET=main

BIN_DIR=bin
SRC_DIR=src
OBJ_DIR=obj

PROTO_DIR=protos/
PROTO_COMPILE_DIR=src/$(PROTO_DIR)

rm       = rm -f

CC       = g++
CFLAGS   = -Wall -std=c++17 -ggdb -pipe -I.
LINKER   = g++
LFLAGS   = $(CFLAGS) -lprotobuf

SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.cc) \
      $(wildcard src/protos/*.cc) \
      $(wildcard src/db_handler/*.cc)

OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cc=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
PROTOS  := $($(PROTO_DIR)/%.proto=$(PROTO_COMPILE_DIR)/%.cc)

$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET): $(PROTOS) $(OBJECTS) 
    echo $(PROTOS)
    @mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)/
    $(LINKER) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc
    @mkdir -p obj/ obj/protos obj/db_handler
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(PROTOS):
    @printf "Compiling protos...\n"
    @cd $(PROTO_DIR) && protoc * --grpc_out=../$(PROTO_COMPILE_DIR)\
        --cpp_out=../$(PROTO_COMPILE_DIR)\
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="/usr/local/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin"\
        && cd ../

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm) -r $(OBJ_DIR)/*
    @$(rm) -r $(BIN_DIR)/*
    @printf "Cleanup complete!\n"
```